# How to rtf string parse in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parsing, uitextview, rtf

SOLVED Larme :

```
**[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[str_rtf dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error]; [yourTextView setAttributedText: attrStr];**
```

I use WebService and get RFT string format. But I can't use in UITextView rtf string.

RTF String convert or parse is possible ?

```
NSString *str_rtf =@"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf250
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 LucidaGrande;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Monaco;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\sl264\slmult1\sb260\ql\qnatural

\f0\fs26 \cf0 You will need to relaunch Xcode after this install to make it load the plugin.\
This package installs both version 2.x and 1.x of DMD, but you can customize the install to get only one or the other.\
With the two versions installed, D for Xcode uses DMD\'a02.x by default. You can override this setting in your Xcode project on a per-target basis by creating a custom build rule in each target\'92s settings. Alternatively, you can change the system default by typing this command from the terminal:\
\pard\pardeftab720\li560\sl264\slmult1\sb260\ql\qnatural

\f1\fs22 \cf0 sudo setdmd 1
\f0\fs26 \
\pard\pardeftab720\sl264\slmult1\sb260\ql\qnatural
\cf0 This will change the symlinks to make the 
\f1\fs22 dmd
\f0\fs26  command point to 
\f1\fs22 dmd1
\f0\fs26 .}"
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Try with NSAttributedString: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-initwithdata?language=objc

Comment: Hi I Know NSAttributedString but I don't have a sample :(

Comment: Larme Thank You ^^, very very thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NSAttributedString with document type NSRTFTextDocumentType.

Comment: Hi I Know NSAttributedString but I don't have a sample :(

Comment: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[str_rtf dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error]; [yourTextView setAttributedText: attrStr]; not working